# How can I find the page object of the page watir is currently on?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

#### Context:

I'm trying to make reusable step definitions that click on page objects on the current page,
e.g. (cucumber step def follows):

```
When(/^the user clicks the "([^"]*)" button$/) do |button|

      click_button = button.downcase.gsub(" ","_")
      @current_page #somehow get current page object on this line
      @current_page.click_button

end
```

#### Problem statement:

I can't find anything that returns the current page object.

#### An explanation for why the obvious solution didn't work:

I thought `@current_page` was already there as something I could use. I looked in the source code for page object, and the variable `@current_page` does exist. Not sure how to use it if I can...

---

BTW, in this case, I have a bunch of testers that can write Gherkin but not necessarily step definitions. We are trying to rapidly finish a bunch of regression tests for an in house app with an unchanging interface.

Comment: I would not use that approach. Clicking buttons is a means to an ends.  The button could change to a swipe when touch screens are more common. I'd focus on the purpose. When you click the button, maybe you are trying to submit a page. Maybe you want the text in a text area to by auto-formatted. My steps will say 'When I submit the purchase'.

Comment: we're doing regression tests for an in-house app. I'm not going to bet my life on it, but it is very unlikely the web interface will ever be on tablets. That said, excellent comment +1

Comment: I believe `@current_page` might only be set when you use the `on` or `visit` page methods (in the PageFactory). Conceptually, how would you know which page object maps to which page?

Comment: I spent some time trying to think of that myself. There is an `if_page` method that can tell if you're on a specific page. It might not be too expensive to check for all the page objects you have. That's a possible way to do what I want. Use `if_page` for every page object you've made until you get a positive. To @DaveMcNulla's credit, it's not looking like we're going to try and write step definitions like this anyway. It is moving all the logic that should be in the step defs and support code into the Gherkin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat at odds with what page-object is trying to provide.

Page object attempts to provide well named actions for interacting with a specific page. If you are wanting to make something that works in general against any page, it will be much easier to write it with watir-webdriver directly.

That said, I agree that a specification based heavily on implementation like that is likely to change. I also would add that it doesn't add much value. I would only continue down this path if you understand and accept that you are using cucumber as a test templating tool instead of a requirements communication tool.

Answer (score 0):

As Justin Ko mentioned, @current_page gets set when you call the `on` or `visit` methods. Its not a good idea to lump something that changes the page object in a step that performs a specific action (in this case clicking a button). You might want a different step that indicates the behavior of the application, such as

```
     the application lands on the <your page> page
```

Then you're can use the name of the page object class to load `@current_page` via the `on` method in that step definition. This also gives the benifit (or curse of having your step having more lower level details) of indicating expected page navigation behavior.